# Is '去+verb' similar to 'to infinitives' in English?

Tags: grammar

I am a collector. I collect sentences which I find interesting or exemplary for certain syntactical structures. I just stumbled over another example of this structure, so I thought I would ask the question here. These are some of my 'to infinitive' collection. There seems to be a remarkable similarity between this use of 去 + verb and the English to + infinitive.

Is this more apparent than real? Maybe this is only Modern Chinese, under  foreign influence. Can this kind of structure be found in Old Chinese?

Does Chinese have a 'to infinitive'?

(these are not all complete sentences, just the bits I saved)

如何去尽责

理解为**去**爱别人

有专门**去**学这方面的知识

可能是错过了真正**去**生活的机会。

用自己的行动做表率，**去**影响自己的子女和整个社会。

Just thought I'd throw this in, 4 去s in one short text:

人们把老师比作“春雨”，把学生比作“春苗“，春苗需要春雨**去**浇灌。老师就如那绵绵的春雨，用丰富的知识**去**开启学生的智慧，用优秀的人格**去**培育学生的品德，用无私的奉献精神**去**熏陶学生的心灵。

Comment: In English using 'to + infinitive' is mostly syntactic; in Chinese '去 + verb' is for semantics (weak causation: in order to/come down to/turn out to).

Comment: So you are saying, this use of 去, which is not rare, is like 而？ I presume you are Chinese. What idea does this use of 去 give you, if you don't mind me asking? The to infinitive is not explained in English, so the questions was a bit difficult.

Comment: 去 in your example generally gives me the impression of some action, like I might imagine someone is actually going to go somewhere to do something when 去 is added, it has no real meanings, for example 如何去尽责=如何尽责 to me, they are both ok, 如何去尽责 just add some slightly more action in it.
(Though I am not Chinese, but am a native Chinese speaker.)

Comment: I am native speaker. As Maroon's answer analyzed in detail, there are a few different meanings of 去 across your examples, but the general idea it summons when I hear this word is either 'go do something' with a sense of purpose and actually doing it as opposed to just reasoning, or 'then' which is similar to 而 like you said.

Comment: @NS.X.: that's a good point, and sounds like as much of a generalization about the matter as we'll ever get. I was not aware of the usage of 而 that way, but the examples I found when looking up this usage suggest that there is indeed some similarity in meaning.

Answer (score 8):

*Note: this answer may well be slightly incomplete.*

Usage of *to* that can be translated to 去 is the case only in specific settings. For instance, in English, *I like to read books* is grammatically correct. However, the Chinese equivalent would be 我喜欢看书: there is no addition of something like 去 before the verb (i.e. 看). **Thus, at the very least, there is no one-size-fits-all equivalent to the English infinitive and to the structure you mentioned.** Now, it's also true that infinitives aren't necessarily used in identical ways across languages (e.g. English sometimes uses the gerund where French might use the infinitive), so I'll move onto a discussion of the structure you suggested itself.

Let's look at an instance of the structure.

> 我们约了在商场去看电影。
>
> (We planned to meet at the shopping mall to see a film.)

**Here, both 去 *and* the English *to* essentially serve as a marker to indicate cause.** *Because* we're going to see a film, we planned to meet at the shopping mall. (Similarly, we could express the same idea in Chinese as: 为了看电影，我们约了在市场.) This is also the case in English, where *to* is being used as a [preposition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to#Preposition). This is also the case in your example of 用自己的行动做表率，去影响自己的子女和整个社会.

Let's look at some other examples, however, to check if that assessment is sufficient. I apologize for the poor quality of the glosses I provide -- but it's also just hard to come up with something better without more context.

- 理解为去爱别人 reads as something like *understanding in order to love other people*. So 去爱 seems to mean *to love* in same sense of the English infinitive (with *to*, in that case). (Similar example, modified from the dictionary: 我命令他们去调查这件事 -- I ordered them to investigate the matter.) **So in some cases, 去 does serve as the *to* part of the infinitive in the most traditional sense.**
- Meanwhile, 有专门去学这方面的知识 reads as "experts who go study ...", and there, 去 is used in a way similar to how it appears in something like 我现在去做功课, or in LINE Dict's [example](http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/example?query=%E5%8E%BB&origin=entry&ref=%23%2Fcnen%2Fentry%2Feb333b4df82d46f4a0dee118b3a81120) of 他去找报纸了. **Here 去 essentially serves the same purpose as *go* in the English *go do something*.**

**So the `去 + VERB` combination should not be interpreted as a parallel to the `to + infinitive` structure in English, since it doesn't always work that way.**
Perhaps it's best to drop the idea of a Chinese infinitive (at least for modern Chinese), because of the lack of Chinese verb inflections -- the idea of an infinitive often involves the idea of it being an uninflected form, and Chinese isn't [a synthetic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_language#Degrees_of_synthesis) by most formulations -- and the failure of English constructions to necessarily correspond consistently to Chinese ones.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In this regard I would recommend a book from Bettelou Los, a Dutch linguist, called "The Rise of the to-infinitive in English", if you are interested. OUP 2005. To write a complete answer, you would have to write a book! Well done! Upvote!

Comment: The conclusion is "去+verb" sometimes works as English infinitive. However, without tense markers, Chinese verbs probably do not distinguish finite and infinite form?

Comment: @DankeXie: yep, that was part of my conclusion (when I said that it wasn't the most productive idea to pursue).